# содержится ли строки одного датафрейма в другом датафрейме

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть два датафрейма с одним стобцом данных (номера):

**DF1**

| Номер |
| --- |
| 218456 |
| 789562 |
| 514 |
| 787862 |
| 894514 |

**DF2**

| Номер |
| --- |
| 893514 |
| 787862 |
| 896514 |
| 789562 |
| 2184 |

Результат: добавить к df2 номера из df1, которые полностью совпадают или частично совпадают (совпадение строго слева)

| num | traf |
| --- | --- |
| 893514 | 0 |
| 787862 | 787862 |
| 896514 | 0 |
| 789562 | 789562 |
| 2184 | 218456 |

Мой вариант:

```
df2['traf'] =df2['num'].apply(lambda x: df1['num'][df1['num'].astype(str).str.contains(str(x))].values[0] if len(df1['num'][df1['num'].astype(str).str.contains(str(x))].values) > 0 else 0)
```

Работает медленно и также добавляет номера, которые могут содержаться не слева, а по середине в том числе.

Comment: Количество строк в обоих датафреймах совпадает и проверять на совпадение нужно только значения из соответствующих строк?

Comment: количество строк не совпадает, в df2 всегда меньше количество строк. Могут быть и другие значения кромое представленных.

Comment: ну найти соответствия - не проблема вообще. но вы же хотите, чтобы они в df2 располагались на соответствующих строках, а не абы как? а что делать, если в df1 совпадений больше, чем строк в df2 (несколько строк в df1 совпадают с одной в df2)?

Comment: как вариант если больше совпадений, то добавить значения списком (в теории)

Comment: еще вариант добавлять не номера, а количество совпадений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, если я правильно понял вопрос, то сделать можно так (я добавил повторяющееся значение в df1 для чистоты эксперимента), однако затратность все равно высокая:

Исходные:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"num":[218456,789562,514,787862,894514,218456]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"num":[893514,787862,896514,789562,2184]})
```

решение:

```
tmp = df1.merge(df2, how="cross").drop_duplicates()
tmp = tmp[tmp.apply(lambda x: str(x["num_x"]).startswith(str(x["num_y"])), axis=1)]
tmp = df2.merge(tmp, left_on="num", right_on="num_y", how="left")#.drop(columns=["num_x"])
tmp["traf"] = tmp.groupby("num")["num_y"].transform("count")
tmp = tmp.drop(columns=["num_x", "num_y"]).drop_duplicates()
```

tmp:

```
      num  traf
0  893514     0
1  787862     1
2  896514     0
3  789562     1
4    2184     2
```

Можно еще после merge сразу сделать новый датафрейм, к примеру, с указанием списка совпадений, а не их количества:

```
res = tmp.groupby("num")["num_x"].apply(lambda x: list(x) if not x.isna().all() else None).reset_index().rename(columns={"num_x":"traf"})
```

res:

```
      num                 traf
0    2184  [218456.0, 21845.0]
1  787862           [787862.0]
2  789562           [789562.0]
3  893514                 None
4  896514                 None
```